# NSIS - Could not write updated PATH to HKLM

Tags: nsis

Good evening, I have a problem when I try to modify the environment variable's path. I'm using the `EnvVarUpdate` nsi tand for some reason when I run the the installer I get this warning.
[image]

Any suggestions are highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it has to do with permissions in your case, as HKLM is not writable for regular users. Are you setting

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin
```

in your script? It causes the installer to pop up the UAC prompt and ask for admin privileges before executing.

Stefan